# Best way in Java to convert a double (representing a price) to a long with a price scale of 8

Tags: java, double, decimal

In Java code where a double is used to represent a price, what is the best way to convert the double to a long with a price scale of 8? For example, {Double} 17.99 would convert to {Long} 1799000000. The double may contain 2 to 4 decimal places.

Simple code such as the following sometimes works correctly:

```
 Double dprice = 17.99;
 Long lprice = (long) (dprice * 100000000);
```

However, for known reasons ([floating point guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/languages/java/)), it may create an unexpected result. For example, in one test {Double} 17.99 converts to {Long} 1798999999.

What are the best options in Java to safely do this conversion? Is BigDecimal necessary in this case?

Comment: "Is BigDecimal necessary in this case?" Storing the "double" price as `BigDecimal` is necessary. By the time you've got `Double dprice = 17.99;`, you've already lost the precision.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It seems that BigDecimal is indeed necessary in this case. I thought there might be some other options such as Math.round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep the precision, as Andy Turner pointed out in the comments, you have to use `BigDecimal`s when doing the multiplications, etc, until the very end. The following should work:

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal dprice = BigDecimal.valueOf(17.99).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    Long lprice = dprice.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100000000)).longValue();
    System.out.println(lprice);
  }
}
```

The `setScale` call can be used to set the exact amount of decimal digits you would like to keep.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The code is working correctly and is definitely an option.